# Change columnname with variable in WHILE loop SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop

Say i have columns PlanSalesMt1, PlanSalesMt2 and so on for the whole year until Mt12 in a table.

Before i created a view where i unioned all the months togheter but that query is pretty slow. Now i want to try the query with a Loop.

My Problem is i can't use the variable in my column names because they get invalid. Is that a way to solve this?

What i mean is i want to loop my question 12 times and change the name of the columns also after what month it is. But i cant make a @i variable and say select PlanSalesMt@1 or PlanSalesMt+@1 or PlanSalesMt+CAST(@1 as varchar) becuase it says invalid column Name.

Comment: You could use dynamic SQL

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of dynamic SQL

```
 DECLARE @ColumnName1 VarChar(20)
 DECLARE @ColumnName2 VarChar(20)
 DECLARE @sql Varchar(1000)
 DECLARE @MyWhere VarChar(20)
 SET @ColumnName1 =   'PlanSalesMt1'
 SET @ColumnName2 =   'PlanSalesMt2'
 SET @MyWhere =   'Books'

 SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @ColumnName1 + ', ' + @ColumnName2 + ' FROM TABLE WHERE ' + @ColumnName1 + ' = ''' + @MyWhere + ''''

 EXEC(@sql)
```

If you change `EXEC(@sql)` to `SELECT @sql` copy into SSMS and run it you will see the query this produces.

Comment: Thanks! But i have 4 columns with different calculations of the months so then i have to make 48 different variables?